# How to get MYSQL to show Zero results when left joining to self? (eg: Monthly Stats)

Tags: mysql, join, self

I have a table with typical statistics on page view and emails.  An email creates a row and page view creates a row...

I want to chart the page views and emails on a daily basis for the past 30 days (for example) so I need to show the day and the value... even if it ZERO.  I cannot have missing days from my results or the chart breaks.

```
PageViews Table:
UniqueID | PageID | DateTime

Emails Table:
UniqueID | SenderEmail | RecipientID | RecipientEmail | DateTime
```

I don't need this to be one query but the problem remains the same for either query... If there are days (or hours, or months.. depending on the group by range) where a specific page was not viewed it is simply omitted from the results array.

Similarly, if there there are days where there were page views but now emails, then the email count query has holes in it...

Essentially, I am trying to create a Google Analytics type chart and need the lines to show ZERO for the days where there are no data in my stats tables...

I think some kind of left self join might work but cannot seem to make it work.  I even messed around with an integer table with only one column (values) and rows for 1-31

Can any of you MYSQL gurus help?

Comment: You want two different charts for each table or some sort of combined chart?

Comment: I am trying to make a combined chart but the common axis goes from today back 31 days... so there are days where a page might not have any views and there are certainly days where there are no emails.  So I need to show the zeros so it plots right.  I could use PHP to pad the results but there has to be a way to do this with a well crafted query?

Answer (score 0):

The standard solution for this problem is to create a helper table and populate it with all of the dates relevant to your anticipated queries.

Here's an applicable SO Q&A:

[How to fill date gaps in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877874/how-to-fill-date-gaps-in-mysql)