# Best method to fill in gaps in a time series in a Mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, gaps-and-islands

I need to fill in the gaps of a time series of a mysql query result set. I'm in the process of testing the option of doing an outer join with a helper table that contains all of the data points of the time series (as indicated in this thread: [How to fill date gaps in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877874/how-to-fill-date-gaps-in-mysql)).

The issue I'm running into is that adding this join significantly increases the query response time (it goes from sub 1 sec to 90 seconds).

Here's the original query:

```
select date_format(fact_data7.date_collected,'%Y-%m') as date_col
   , date_format(fact_data7.date_collected,'%d-%H:%i:%s') as time_col
   , fact_data7.batch_id,fact_data7.value as fdvalue,entities.ticker as ticker
   , date_format(fact_data7.date_collected,'%Y-%m-%d') as date_col2
   , date_format(fact_data7.date_collected,'%Y') as year 
from fact_data7  
JOIN entities on fact_data7.entity_id=entities.id  
where (1=1)
  AND ((entities.id= 963
      AND fact_data7.metric_id=1
      ))
  AND date_format(fact_data7.date_collected,'%Y-%m') > '2008-01-01'
order by date_col asc
```

and here is the query with the outer join to the helper table (month_fill) added:

```
select date_format(month_fill.date,'%Y-%m') as date_col
    , date_format(fact_data7.date_collected,'%d-%H:%i:%s') as time_col
    , fact_data7.batch_id,fact_data7.value as fdvalue
    , entities.ticker as ticker
    , date_format(fact_data7.date_collected,'%Y-%m-%d') as date_col2
    , date_format(fact_data7.date_collected,'%Y') as year 
from fact_data7
JOIN entities
  on fact_data7.entity_id=entities.id  
RIGHT OUTER JOIN month_fill
   on date_format(fact_data7.date_collected,'%Y-%m') =  date_format(month_fill.date,'%Y-%m')  
where (1=1)
  AND (
      (entities.id= 963 AND fact_data7.metric_id=1)
      OR (entities.id is null and fact_data7.metric_id is null)
      )
  AND date_format(month_fill.date,'%Y-%m') > '2008-01-01'
order by date_col asc
```

Can I restructure the query to improve the performance is there an alternate solution to achieve what I'm looking for?

Update 11/15:

Here's the EXPLAIN output for the 1st query:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  entities    const   PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   const   1   Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  fact_data7  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    230636  Using where
```

Here's the EXPLAIN output for the 2nd query:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  month_fill  index   NULL    date    8   NULL    204     Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  fact_data7  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    230636  Using where
1   SIMPLE  entities    eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   findata.fact_data7.entity_id    1   Using where
```

Comment: What where the results of EXPLAIN?

Comment: Added it to the initial question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without even looking at refactoring the query I would start by adding an index on the date columns fact_data7.data_collected and month_fill.date. The range query ">" you are doing is slowing down the process and adding an index should theoretically speaking increase the performance but you need enough record otherwise managing the index will only slow down because of the processing involved in managing the index.

See this mysql documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimization-indexes.html

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve but you could try to do it using the `ifnull(value1,value2)` function of mysql. Your query could be somewhat like the following:

```
select ifnull(date_format(fact_data7.date_collected,'%Y-%m'),date_format(month_fill.date,'%Y-%m')) as date_col, 
date_format(fact_data7.date_collected,'%d-%H:%i:%s') as time_col, 
fact_data7.batch_id,
fact_data7.value as fdvalue,
entities.ticker as ticker,
date_format(fact_data7.date_collected,'%Y-%m-%d') as date_col2 ,
date_format(fact_data7.date_collected,'%Y') as year 
from fact_data7 , month_fill
JOIN entities on fact_data7.entity_id=entities.id  
where ((entities.id= 963 AND fact_data7.metric_id=1) OR (entities.id is null and fact_data7.metric_id is null))
and date_format(fact_data7.date_collected,'%Y-%m') =  date_format(month_fill.date,'%Y-%m') --you will need a condition similar to this depends on the data
AND date_format(fact_data7.date_collected,'%Y-%m')>'2008-01-01'
order by date_col asc
```

Comment: I do already have an index on date_collected in fact_data7. I just added an index on the date field in the helper table, but that table is relatively much smaller (240 rows vs ~20000 in fact_data7) and the index didn't have any effect on performance.

Comment: can you do a count on the second query with the second join. I suspect you might be returning 240 times more records than expected?

Comment: It's not doing a cartesian product, if that's what you're suspecting. The first query returns 18958 rows, and the second query returns 19055 rows (with the empty months filled in).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's worth trying to rewrite `where` in order not to use `date_format(date_collected)` . You say you have an index on this field, but it's never used(field is an argument of the function,
 MySQL doesn't support function-based indexes)