# SQL - Select data on a period with a default value

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, date, select

I want to select data from a table, get the result in JavaScript and print it in a graph (x = date, y = numbers)

I have the following `DATA` table (note: I tried to put it in markdown so it appears as an HTML table, but it doesn't seems to work):

```
| date    | number |
|---------|--------|
| 2015-01 | 12     |
| 2015-02 | 7      |
| 2015-04 | 4      |
```

and the following SQL select:

```
SELECT date_format(date, '%Y-%m') AS date, number
FROM DATA
WHERE date >= '2015-01' AND date <= '2015-05'
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date;
```

which gives me exactly the same table as output. However, what I'd want is a row per each months with `0` if the month is not recorded. For instance, March is not recorded in the database, so the result that I want:

```
| date    | number |
|---------|--------|
| 2015-01 | 12     |
| 2015-02 | 7      |
| 2015-03 | 0      |
| 2015-04 | 4      |
| 2015-05 | 0      |
```

the table goes to May, because in the SELECT I want every months between January and May.

The question is: is there a way to do it in SQL, or do I have to post-process the results in JavaScript to add the empty months in my final table?

thanks for your help

---

*edit*: the begin and end dates are variable and can cover several years. So, I guess it is possible to do something with a special table containing the months but I have no idea how...
If the answer is to post-process, it's OK (disappointing but OK ^^)

---

*edit2*: the problem is "gap filling" as stated @mauro. It looks quite complex in MySQL, so I'm going to post-process my request.

see [How to fill date gaps in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877874/how-to-fill-date-gaps-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

I would create a second table `DATA2` with **one row per month** and number=zero. Then, instead of selecting:

```
FROM DATA
```

I would select from:

```
FROM ( SELECT * FROM DATA UNION ALL SELECT * FROM DATA2 ) D
```

This way... if DATA contains values for a given month, you will get totals from DATA, if not... you will get zero from DATA2

Comment: That's an idea. The problem is that the begin and end dates are variable and can cover several years :/ I'm editing my question
I was hoping that SQL has a sort of date calculator that could achieve my wishes...

Comment: @Rémi With other databases - having "gap filling" capabilities - it will be much easier and not that "rude" :-)

Comment: "gap filling"! with the correct keywords, I get better search results :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877874/how-to-fill-date-gaps-in-mysql

It seems that in MySQL it is complicated, so I think I'm going to post-process because it looks very ugly to create a temporary table just for that... but I don't know what is the best for performance.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample with no temp table. it use the sequence ENGINE. The only difference is you must fill the start date an the count of month (seq_0_to_4).

```
SELECT `DATE`, SUM(number) as number
FROM (
  SELECT
    date_format( IF(d.`DATE` IS NULL, init.`DATE`, d.`DATE`) ,'%Y-%m') AS `DATE`
    , IF(d.number IS NULL,0,d.number) as number
  FROM (
    SELECT '2015-01-01' + INTERVAL seq MONTH AS `DATE`, 0 AS number
    FROM seq_0_to_4
    ) AS INIT
  LEFT JOIN DATA d ON date_format(d.`DATE`,'%Y-%m') = date_format( init.`DATE` ,'%Y-%m')
  ) AS result
GROUP BY `DATE`
ORDER BY `DATE`;
```

**Result**

```
+---------+--------+
| DATE    | number |
+---------+--------+
| 2015-01 |      7 |
| 2015-02 |      0 |
| 2015-03 |      7 |
| 2015-04 |      0 |
| 2015-05 |      0 |
+---------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Table**

```
MariaDB > select * from data;
+------------+--------+
| date       | number |
+------------+--------+
| 2015-01-01 |      4 |
| 2015-01-02 |      3 |
| 2015-03-05 |      7 |
+------------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB >
```

Comment: This may work, but is specific to MariaDB, unfortunately. The sequence engine doesn't exist in MySQL, only in MariaDB 10+... So, I'll let my original post as is (the *edit2* explain the problem come from the lack of features of MySQL).

I would have install MariaDB if I could, but it is for an existing solution...

I just have a question in your request: you have `IF(d.number IS NULL,0,d.number)`, and then you select `0 AS number` in `INIT`. I guess this is not required as you directly use `0` in your `IF` before, right?

Comment: yes, sorry. you can remove the  0 as number. my error