# Determine the days a state machine was in a state

Tags: mysql, state-machine

I have a state machine that begins in state 1(true) and can move to state 2 (provisionally false), from provisionally false it can move back to state 1 or to state 3(false). State 3 can loop on itself or go to state 1.

If a state goes from state 2 to state 3 then the state machine is `false` from the time it was in state 2 until it goes back to state 1 (from state 3). However, if it goes from state 2 back to state 1, then it was never in a `false` state.

I log the transitions in a database so it looks like:

```
+----+------------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+---------------------+
| id | state_machine_id | current_state | new_state | last_event_id | ts                  |  
+----+------------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+---------------------+
|  1 |                1 |             0 |         1 |          NULL | 2018-12-26 16:18:51 |
|  2 |                1 |             1 |         2 |             1 | 2018-12-26 18:21:01 |
|  3 |                1 |             2 |         1 |             2 | 2018-12-26 18:35:24 |
|  4 |                1 |             1 |         2 |             3 | 2018-12-26 18:51:01 |
|  5 |                1 |             2 |         1 |             4 | 2018-12-26 18:51:42 |
|  6 |                1 |             1 |         2 |             5 | 2018-12-27 20:03:01 |
|  7 |                2 |             0 |         1 |          NULL | 2018-12-28 02:07:49 |
|  8 |                1 |             2 |         3 |             6 | 2018-12-28 02:15:01 |
+----+------------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+---------------------+
```

State 0 is a placeholder for a starting state and last `last_event_id` refers to the last event for the particular state machine.

Problem:
Receive startDate, endDate, and state_machine_id

Return 2D array where each element has a date and whether the state machine was false on that day.

Example:

Input: start='2018-12-26', end='2018-12-30', stateMachine = 1

Output:

```
+------------+-----------+
| day        | is_false  |
+------------+-----------+
| 2018-12-26 |         0 |
| 2018-12-27 |         0 |
| 2018-12-28 |         1 |
| 2018-12-29 |         1 |
| 2018-12-30 |         1 |
+------------+-----------+
```

I have done the above programmatically, below is my psuedo-code:

```
transitionsInSpan = db->run('SELECT * FROM transitions where ts >= $start and ts <= $end and state_machine_id = $stateMachine')->all()
if transitionsInSpan empty: //edge cases
    $closestToStart = db->run('SELECT current_state, new_state from transitions WHERE state_machine_id = $stateMachine AND ts < $start ORDER BY ts DESC LIMIT 1')->first()
    if(current_state = 2 and new_state = 3):
        return dates with all true
    else if(new_state = 2):
        get the closestToEnd ... all true if new_state = 3
    return false for all dates
else:
    listOfDates = dates between start and end dates (inclusive)
    iterate through listOfDates:
        ...this gets kind of messy and convoluted
```

I am now trying with mysql:

```
SELECT MAX(
    IF
    (
        new_state = 3, 
        true, 
        IF 
        ( 
            id IN 
            (
                SELECT last_event_id from transitions WHERE new_state = 3
            ), true, false
        )
    )
) as is_false,
date(ts) as ts
FROM transitions
WHERE state_machine_id = 1
GROUP BY ts;
```

The above results in the following:

```
+-----------+------------+
| is_false  | ts         |
+-----------+------------+
|         0 | 2018-12-26 |
|         1 | 2018-12-27 |
|         1 | 2018-12-28 |
+-----------+------------+
```

But I still need to pad the ends with the right dates and booleans (i.e. include 12-29 and 12-30 as true), also I am not sure how to capture dates missing in between...

Comment: Add expected output from your sample data

Comment: Please edit your question to include the SQL queries you have tried. The `last_event_id` column can be very helpful to get the previous entry, so it will most likely be a `JOIN` query on the table itself. Also, please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query on SQL related questions and provide all the necessary information (and the SQL queries you have tried).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877874/how-to-fill-date-gaps-in-mysql might be helpful as well because you need the individual days between the state changes as well.

Comment: I have added my updates, thanks