# How to add not existing record and return it with zero value in Mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

**QUERY:**

```
 SELECT month(date_created), count(a.ticket_num) 
            FROM ticket as a 
            LEFT JOIN user_management as b on b.engineer_id = a.ticket_engineer 
            WHERE b.tl_id = 'sample_id'
            AND year(date_created) = '2019'
            GROUP BY extract(year from date_created), extract(month from date_created)
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT:**

```
  month | ticket_num
----------------------
    2   |     12
    4   |     24
    6   |     78
```

**EXPECTED SAMPLE OUTPUT:**

```
 month | ticket_num
----------------------
    1   |     0
    2   |     12
    3   |     0
    4   |     24
    5   |     0
    6   |     78
```

As you can see the above expected output, i'm trying to place all existing month in the first column and set all the count to zero if not existed in the second column. As of now, i only have the query for sorting the ticket count by month that is existed when the ticket is created.

Comment: you should try  inner join ..

Comment: What about the months 7,8,9,10,11,12 ? Or, you want to consider all the months only upto the maximum month with available data ?

Comment: yes, you're right, up to the max available data only.

Comment: You may do it with your php code.

Comment: As Kris suggested, simplest solution would be to just get the data from query. Run a loop in PHP to find missing months, and add their key to data array with value 0 (if not found). Doing it in query alone, will unnecessarily complicate it, and will be inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches to this problem. One is [pure SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877874/how-to-fill-date-gaps-in-mysql) for example.

But I would say a PHP based solution is simpler. Basically you need to get your data into *array*, then create a loop that outputs the desired months order, and have a condition that sees whether we have a corresponding row in our array and outputs ether the actual data or a zero accordingly.

The only tricky part is to have such an array that would let us check the data availability. For this we have to *index* it with month numbers. Not a big deal actually

```
$sql = "SELECT month(date_created), count(a.ticket_num) ...";
$res = $mysqli($sql);
$data = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($res)) {
    $data[$row[0]] = $row[1];
}
```

Now `$data` is an array indexed by the month number. The rest is a primitive loop

```
foreach (range(1,12) as $month) {
    echo $data[$month] ?: 0;
}
```

On a side note I would like to advertise using PDO as opposed to mysqli for your database interactions as this case clearly displays the superiority of the former. Using PDO we can get the indexed array right away, without an explicit loop, thanks to a [special fetch mode](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_KEY_PAIR):

```
$sql = "SELECT month(date_created), count(a.ticket_num) ...";
$data = $data = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
```

That's all!

Comment: Thank you for all your time. I already solved it via loop, by looping 12 times going to the query and returning it with zero if the query is false.

Comment: Running the same SELECT query in a loop is a bad practice.